# why prefer to use containment to inheritance?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I remembered that I read once in a book that teaches

try to use composition as far as you could. I forgot the reasons now, anyone could give the hint?

Comment: You can argue this (as is the case with many other rules), but inheritance is rigid and finalized at compile time, also inheritance breaks encapsulation.

Comment: I think you meant composition rather than containment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prefer composition over inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

I had been confused same as you until I found this explanation:
[Inheritance is Bad: Code Reuse](http://blogs.perl.org/users/sid_burn/2014/03/inheritance-is-bad-code-reuse-part-1.html) Great example where author explain inheritance based on example typically used to show why inheritance is "great".

Answer (score -1):

Favor 'object composition' over 'class inheritance'. (Gang of Four 1995:20)
Read the book